# The logic for collision detection of object with the window form is not working right.

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I am trying to detect when the object in a form get bigger than the form itself. When it does that a MessageBox should appear with the text "Game over".

This is what I've done:

For x-axis

```
  private void CollisionXForward()
    {
        int x = this.Width; //the width of the form is 493

        //if the position of x-axis of the rectangle goes over the limit of the form...
        if (rc.PositionX  >= x )
        {
           //...game over
            MessageBox.Show("Game over");

        }
        else
        {
              //move the object +5 every time i press right arrow
            rc.MoveXForward();

        }
```

The thing is that the rectangle dissapears because it goes a step further than the frame itself. I have "fixed" the problem by having this statement:

```
if (rc.PositionX  >= x - (rc.Width * 2))
```

instead of the normal one you see at the code. But it doesn't work when I do the same thing with the y-axis or when I change the size of the rectangle.

Comment: Don't you mean `rc.Width / 2`?

Comment: You should use `ClientRectangle.Width` and `ClientRectangle.Height`, because the regular `Width` and `Height` include the title bar and borders of the form. Perhaps that's the problem with vertical.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError neither of the suggestions worked

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I think the problem may be that the x axis of the rectangle starts at the left side. But I want to se when the right side of x-axis collide with the frame. Thanks for the help

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the rc.Width returns the width of the rectangle. The width of it is 20. What I tried to do is to see when the right side of the rectangle hits the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if (rc.PositionX + rc.Width >= ClientRectangle.Width)
```

and

```
if (rc.PositionY + rc.Height >= ClientRectangle.Height)
```

Edit:

```
private void CollisionXForward()
{
    rc.MoveXForward();

    //if the position of x-axis of the rectangle goes over the limit of the form...
    if (rc.PositionX + rc.Width >= ClientRectangle.Width )
    {
       //...game over
        MessageBox.Show("Game over");

    }
}
```

or

```
private void CollisionXForward()
{
    //if the position of x-axis of the rectangle goes over the limit of the form...
    if (rc.PositionX + step + rc.Width >= ClientRectangle.Width ) //step is 5 in your case
    {
       //...game over
        MessageBox.Show("Game over");

    }
    else
    {
        //move the object +5 every time i press right arrow
        rc.MoveXForward();

    }
}
```

valter

Comment: it worked when I added with 5 instead of one. Can it be because the rectangle moves +5 every time i press the button?

Comment: @Mnemonics Your problem is that you first check and then move. Do the opposite: first move and then check.

Comment: what do you mean? Should I first call the method rc.MoveXForward and then if (rc.PositionX + rc.Width + 1 >= x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Game over");

            }

Comment: @Mnemonics There are two ways to do this. The first one(see edit). The second on adding the step(in your case 5).Both are correct Chose one.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `rc` object a `BoundingBox` property returning a `Rectangle`. Then the test becomes easy

```
if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(rc.BoundingBox)) {
    rc.MoveXForward();
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Game over");
}
```

If you need to leave space for a step then test like this:

```
if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(rc.BoundingBox.Inflate(step, step))) {
    rc.MoveXForward();
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Game over");
}
```

---

```
public class MyRcClass
{
   ...
   public Rectangle BoundingBox
   {
       get { return new Rectangle(PositionX, PositionY, Width, Height); }
   }
}
```

Comment: this actually did work very well. But I like more as said to first move the object and then check. I think I will use your suggestion in the future. Thank you.